# Prove $\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}\ge \sqrt{7\left(a^3+b^3+c^3+a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+b^2a+a^2c+c^2b\right)-3}$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ and $a,b,c\ge 0$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

With $a,b,c\ge 0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, prove $\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}\ge \sqrt{7\left(a^3+b^3+c^3+a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+b^2a+a^2c+c^2b\right)-3}$.

I don't know when equality holds for this problem, can you give me some hint? Thank!

Comment: I assume the term under the big square root is supposed to be symmetric in $a,b,c$? Note that in that case it is equal to $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)=a+b+c$ which makes the term inside square root negative.

Comment: @quarague Oh, I'm sorry, I have seen my problem again and I have changed it, now I wonder can the term inside square root be negative

Comment: @user628755   There are two $c^2a$ inside square root. Is one of them $a^2c$?

Comment: @RiverLi Sorry I have changed it, how difficult it is :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to prove that
$$(\sqrt{a + b} + \sqrt{b + c} + \sqrt{c + a})^2 \ge 7(a + b + c) - 3$$
or
$$2a + 2b + 2c + \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} 2\sqrt{(a + b)(b + c)} \ge 7(a + b + c) - 3.$$

Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality and GM-HM inequality, we have
$$\sqrt{(a + b)(b + c)} \ge b + \sqrt{ca} \ge b + \frac{2ca}{c + a}
\ge b + \frac{2ca}{a + b + c}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$4a + 4b + 4c + \frac{4(ab + bc + ca)}{a + b + c} \ge 7(a + b + c) - 3$$
or
$$4a + 4b + 4c + \frac{2 \cdot [(a + b + c)^2 - 1]}{a + b + c} \ge 7(a + b + c) - 3$$
or
$$(a + b + c - 1)(2 - a - b - c) \ge 0$$
which is true (easy).

We are done.

Comment: amazing! would you like to please tell me your thought process behind this solution?

Comment: @PhilosophicalNature It is a quit known trick to deal with $\sqrt{(a + b)(a + c)} \ge a + \sqrt{bc}$ (C-S inequality) and $\sqrt{a + b} + \sqrt{b + c} + \sqrt{c + a}$. You can find many posts involving this trick in AoPS. For example, see #6 in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1309061p7007111